# Unable to create SymmetricKey

Tags: c++, visual-c++, botan

First of all version of Botan I'm using is Botan-1.10.9
And I'm writing a managed wrapper in Visual C++

Following this example, I'm trying to create a SymmetricKey from the hash of a string so I can pass it into the fe1_encrypt method of the FPE module

Signature of fe1_encrypt is

```
BigInt FPE::fe1_encrypt(const BigInt &n, const BigInt &X, const SymmetricKey &key, const std::vector<byte> &tweak)
```

I want the value I pass into the key parameter to be hash of the plaintext (not possibility to decrypt)  So really I don't care about it being a SymmetricKey, just need that type because the method requires it as a parameter.

But in their example they have passed the SymmetricKey their hash method that returns an std:vector

However there is no constructor for SymmetricKey that takes this type.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:  I tried this with no luck

```
std::vector<byte> re = SHA_1(plaintextAsString);
Botan::OctetString key(re, re.size());
```

ERROR

Error   15  error C2664: 'Botan::OctetString::OctetString(Botan::RandomNumberGenerator &,size_t)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'Botan::RandomNumberGenerator &'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://fossies.org/dox/Botan-1.10.9/classBotan_1_1OctetString.html), `SymmetricKey` (which is just a typedef for `OctetString`) can take a byte array and length as constructor.  Alternatively, you can encode the key as a hex string.  If you already have the key as `std::vector<byte>`, then this should suffice:

```
std::vector<byte> keybytes;
// ...fill the vector...

SymmetricKey key( keybytes.data(), keybytes.size() );
```

Later versions of Botan define another constructor `OctetString (const std::vector<byte> &in)`.

Comment: OMG Thanks so much!. I was stuck for so long.  It was the data() method I was missing.  This works.

Comment: Instead of `keybytes.data()`, you might also commonly see `&keybytes[0]` used when someone is obtaining a pointer to the start of a vector's data.  I prefer the `data` method.